# The should add a C.H.I.P category to Stack Exchange!

Tags: feature-request, area-51

We really need a C.H.I.P category in Stack Exchange! That would be great!

For those of you who don't know what that is, it's a raspberry-pi-zero-like computer for 9$ CAD. It's mostly like the RPI zero in performance and "computerness", but it uses a ARMv7 architecture instead of rpi's ARMv6. It has 80 GPIO ports, built in Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0, and has the option of buying additional add-ons (HDMI port, etc.)

The point is, because the C.H.I.P is just so amazing for its price, ([it's an amazing alternative for all other microcontrollers and the RPI zero,](http://makezine.com/2015/11/28/chip-vs-pi-zero/)) it needs its own category right here in Stack exchange!

Comment: Barzonz gave you the right answer, but it will likely get rejected, I'm sure, as there isn't a large enough user base. Also, you stole my avatar!

Comment: @Barzonz haha, that's actually my yt channel picture... Anyways, can you please vote for it on aera 51? P.S nice avatar.

Comment: Note that I don't think you will get much support for your proposal - the chip doesn't seem to be fully released yet and hence there isn't a large userbase.

Comment: Just because something is amazing doesn't mean it deserve its own Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

You can propose a new site via http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Then other people consider your idea, ask sample questions, and commit to the concept.  Take a visit and see it makes sense to propose it over there.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: start with this link and propose it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology